# execute a function after many setStates finish updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have a function which sets the state. I want to call a function after I set the state. Here's my code:

```
sanityChecking() {
    this.checkFirstName();
    this.checkSecondName();
    this.checkDomain();

    // Call this function after the top 3 functions finish setting their state
    this.Predict();
}
```

The first three functions have `setState` in the them. Im trying to run the fourth function `this.Predict` after they're all DONE updating. Any ideas how?

Comment: Please include the actual code using the built in code button on the editor. Don't link to images since they can disappear.

Answer (score 1):

`setState` can set multiple states inline, and in addition to that, it has a callback function like this:

```
this.setState({
    stateToChange: value,
    anotherStateToChange: value2,
    thirdValueToChange: value3
}, () => {
    console.log('I finished changing the states');
});
```

So for your code, you can either create a `function` that sets the state, and takes a parameter as a callback. Then add that callback parameter in the second argument of `setState`. Like this:

```
function checkFirstName(stateCallback) {
    setState({firstName: 'Charley'}, stateCallback);
}
```

then just chain them all together. Or you can use set multiple states at once, and call the callback of `setState` as the second argument, like I showed above.

For more info on this, I ran into a [cool article on setState](https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296) which is worth reading. (I have no affiliations. Just a quick google search :)

Let me know if this helps, or if you have anymore question.

Answer (score 0):

because this.setState is async. Chances are your three functions may even be running in one update. What you could do, instead of calling this.setState inside each function, you could return the value of what you would like to update. This way, you could use the second argument of setState, which is a callback.

```
sanityChecking() {
  this.setState({
    first: this.checkFirstName(),
    second: this.checkSecondName(),
    domain: this.checkDomain(),
  }, () => {
    this.setState({ predict: this.Predict());
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an argument to each function which is the callback to the setState call.

So in each of your three functions it would look something like the following:

```
function checkFirstName(setStateCallback) {
    ...
    setState({...}, setStateCallback)
    ...
}
```

and in your main function you could chain them together:

```
function sanityChecking() {
  this.checkFirstName(function () {
      this.checkSecondName(function () {
          this.checkDomain(function () {
              this.Predict();
          })
      })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function instead of an object in your setState calls. Read more [in the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

The function takes as it's first argument the previous state and the props at the time it is called. This will ensure that the state is up to date.

```
this.setState(
  (state, props) => ({
    predict: `${state.firstName} ${state.secondName}`
  })
);
```